# Get Raw Http Source Code from WebView

Tags: android, webview, okhttp

1. I am working with `WebView`. Now I need to get the source of a webpage.
   I have tried with `JavascriptInterface` but the source has been affected by `javascript` ( not the same when I use "view-source:" on chrome).
2. Can we use `Cookie` from `WebView` to `OkHttp`? I've login into Google and my cookie is saved in `WebView`, now i want to get some data but in `OkHttp` not in `WebView`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get it by hitting the web url through `DefaultHttpClient`

as:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://yoururl.com"); // Set the action you want to do
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
    sb.append(line + "\n");

String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

is.close(); // Close the stream
```

you have to add some timeout params as well:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,3000); // 3s max for connection
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 4000); // 4s max to get data
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```

**EDIT:**

You can get cookies from webview as:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
    Log.d(TAG, "All the cookies in a string:" + cookies);
}
```

Comment: But I need cookie of WebView to access that page

Comment: And how to use that cookie on OkHttpClient ( or whatever client)? The site I want to get HTML on a page which only be access if I have login to it (I've already login on WebView)

Comment: I don't understand your point? You are trying these cookies to transfer on other client?

Comment: I want to take cookies of WebView to use in OkHttpClient (or some other http client)